# Why LiveData returns null in ViewModel?

Tags: java, android

My LiveData<> return null when i try to get value from it?

> MainActivity

**

> Here is my error: //Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List
>   com.xllnc.mvvmexample.entity.ApiResponse.getIssues()' on a null object
>   reference

**

```
mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ListIssueViewModel.class);
mViewModel.getApiResponse().observe(this, apiResponse -> mAdapter.addIssues(apiResponse.getIssues()));
mViewModel.loadIssues("square", "retrofit");
```

> ViewModel

```
public class ListIssueViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<ApiResponse> mApiResponse;
    private IssueRepository mIssueRepository;

    public ListIssueViewModel(){
        mApiResponse = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        mIssueRepository = new IssueRepositoryImpl();
    }

    public LiveData<ApiResponse> getApiResponse(){
        return mApiResponse;
    }

    public void loadIssues(String user, String repo){
        ApiResponse response = mIssueRepository.getIssues(user, repo).getValue();
        mApiResponse.setValue(response);
    }
}
```

> Repository

```
public class IssueRepositoryImpl implements IssueRepository {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/";
    private GitHubApiService mApiService;

    public IssueRepositoryImpl(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build();
        mApiService = retrofit.create(GitHubApiService.class);
    }

public LiveData<ApiResponse> getIssues(String owner, String repo) {
        final MutableLiveData<ApiResponse> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        Call<List<Issue>> call = mApiService.getIssues(owner, repo);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Issue>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Issue>> call, Response<List<Issue>> response) {
                liveData.setValue(new ApiResponse(response.body()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Issue>> call, Throwable t) {
                liveData.setValue(new ApiResponse(t));
            }
        });
        return liveData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is about asynchronous nature of Rest api or retrofit calls while you are trying to get response synchronously.

```
 public void loadIssues(String user, String repo){
        ApiResponse response = mIssueRepository.getIssues(user, repo).getValue();
        mApiResponse.setValue(response);
    }
```

Sets ApiResponse even it's not retrieved from the service.

Use `Transformations.switchMap` to get response and observe it correctly.

Comment: But why, when i call `mIssueRepository.getIssues` it will make request and get LiveData<ApiResponse>. And then i set it to MutableLiveData? isn't it ?

Comment: @Rarity7- your code looks similar to what is there in the guides https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide. Check UserRepository. Just return the livedata in loadIssues and observer it in activity. initially there will no data and later you setvalue when you have data. so setadapter when you have data.

Comment: First time you create `final MutableLiveData<ApiResponse> liveData = new MutableLiveData<>();` it has `null` value and you set  `mApiResponse.setValue(response)` with this null value and you try to get list from a null value in MainActivity. You can also use if(apiResponse != null) in observe method

Comment: As i stated in the answer there maybe few ms between call result but you set data as null initially and that is the problem. Using Transition.switchMap which also uses MediatorLiveData is one of the solutions or you can check for null.

Answer (score -1):

don't make liveData in the method in repository final